# 15.04 Unity accessing application menu with keyboard

Tags: appmenu, 15.04, keyboard-accelerators

I just upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04. In 14.10 and earlier, I could access the application's menu from the keyboard using alt followed by a letter key for a particular menu. For example: I like to resize a terminal to one of the predefined sizes in terminal's "Terminal" menu using, e.g. alt-t-1. Now the alt key shows the menu, but there seems to be no hot keys to access the menus from there. It doesn't work from either locally integrated menus or global (in the top bar).

Answer (score 3):

It never fails for me to find the answer right after I post...

Terminal was the only app I really use the keyboard menu access. It seems all other apps work OK for keyboard access (alt-). The terminal's default changed during the upgrade and the fix is to go to terminal's first "Terminal" menu on the left (there are 2 Terminal menus) and in preferences, check the box for "Enable mnemonics (such as Alt-F to open the file menu".